# Why sprintf('%u', inet_pton($ip)) return 0?

Tags: php, ipv6, ipv4

No matter if `$ip=4.23.45.61` or `2a00:8640:0001:0000:0224:36ff:feef:1d89`, why does `sprintf('%u', inet_pton($ip))` or `sprintf('%x', inet_pton($ip))` always return 0?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably because `inet_pton($ip)` doesn't return a string, so it's trying to `sprintf` a string with another type, which cannot be done so it returns a 0 (error).

Answer (score 3):

`inet_pton` returns a binary string containing the packed representation of the address. It's not a number, so it can't be formatted using `%u` or `%x`, which are for numbers.

You can use `inet_ntop` if you want to convert the packed binary string back into a human readable string.